# How can I set a variable in *.php when i use grunt-php?

Tags: php, node.js, gruntjs

I use grunt-php in my project to run a  php server, I have config Gruntfile.json like this.

[image: screenhsot of Gruntfile.json]

but I want to set a variable to *.php, so that I can get value like this.

```
<?php echo isset($a) ? $a : ''>
```

How can I set it?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for something as copy-pasteable as as json content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [grunt-php-set-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-php-set-constant).

```
setPHPConstant: {
    stage: {
        constant    : 'a',
        value       : 'stage-<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>',
        file        : 'aFolderInYourProject/fileToWriteConstantTo.php'
    }
}
```

You should create the file"fileToWriteConstantTo.php" beforehand and add the line

```
define('a', 'blah');
```

When you run the task it will change the constant.

Otherwise you could use [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace) and search and replace your exact string e.g. "$a = 'blah'"